# Can you detect a menu click (specifically an 'unhide sheet' command)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a particular sheet/tab on a Google Sheets document which I would like to hide from a user based on certain criteria. I can hide the sheet no problem but it doesn't stop the user from simply unhiding the sheet. I'd like to trap their attempt and re-hide the sheet.

Is this possible?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to track or get if the unhide button was pressed but there is an alternative way to do it.This may irritate the users that will keep on unhiding the sheet.

## [OnEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit)

> The `onEdit()` trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet. Most `onEdit()` triggers use the information in the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to respond appropriately. For example, the `onEdit(e)` function below sets a comment on the cell that records the last time it was edited.

## [hideSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideSheet())

> Hides this sheet. Has no effect if the sheet is already hidden. If this method is called on the only visible sheet, it will throw an exception.

Code Sample:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.hideSheet();
```

## OR

---

## Class Protection

> Access and modify protected ranges and sheets. A protected range can protect either a static range of cells or a named range. A protected sheet may include unprotected regions.

```
// Protect the active sheet, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Sample protected sheet');

// Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
// permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
```

Hope this helps!